# Сколько оперативной памяти можно впихнуть в Asus x555LF

Tags: память, ноутбук, asus

На сайте производителя сказано, что Asus x555LF комплектуется 8 Гб оперативной памяти. Отсюда непонятно, это максимальный поддерживаемый объем или это коммерческое ограничение для недорогой серии Х.

Какой максимально поддерживаемый объем оперативной памяти в ноутбуке  Asus x555LF?

Comment: Чип, проц, количество слотов

Comment: @eri процессор i3-5010U

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме.

Comment: @mkkik вполне онтопик

Comment: ну проц поддерживат до 32гб

Comment: @eri, спорно, это же не вопрос о конфигурации или администрировании.

Comment: это вопрос о конфигурации

Answer (score 5):

[На сайте производителя](https://www.asus.com/ru/Laptops/ASUS-Laptop-X555LF/specifications/) написано:

> Оперативная память - DDR3L 1600 МГц SDRAM, 1 слот(а) DIMM, **макс. до 8 Гб**

Так что очень понятно - это МАКСИМАЛЬНЫЙ поддерживаемый объём. Он определяется возможностями чипсета, и не поддаётся дальнейшему увеличению.